# keep the center of a sprite fixed while rotating

Tags: rotation, sprite, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I'm using Cocos2d-js v3 to create a [jackpot-spinner](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamstime.com%2Fillustration%2Fgame-spin.html&psig=AOvVaw0ofL9EPNFVMw6iL-an-hDN&ust=1593629449074000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCPjdpr6aquoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD). When I'm rotating the spinner wheel sprite, it wobbles, as in it moves in x,y axis slightly too while rotataing. How can I keep the sprite fixed while rotating? I'm new to Cocos2d-js.

Here is my creating the sprite code -

```
sprite = new cc.Sprite.create(res.wheel_png);
sprite.setPosition(cc.p(size.width/2, size.height/2));
this.addChild(sprite, 0);
```

And rotation code -

```
var rand = Math.random();
var sprite_action = cc.RotateBy.create(2, 1370);
var repeat_action = cc.Repeat.create(sprite_action, rand);
sprite.runAction(repeat_action);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method is deprecated, as are some others. Check out [this](https://cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.5/da/d58/deprecated.html) page for list of all things deprecated.

As per the cocos [docs](https://docs.cocos2d-x.org/api-ref/js/v3x/) for v3, (look up "rotateby")

> **Field Detail**   <static> {cc.RotateBy} cc.RotateBy.create
>
> Please use cc.rotateBy instead. Rotates a cc.Node object clockwise a number of degrees by modifying it's rotation attribute. Relative to its properties to modify.
> Deprecated:since v3.0
>
> **Please use cc.rotateBy instead.**

You need to use it like this:

```
var rand = Math.random();
var sprite_action = cc.rotateBy(2, 1370);
var repeat_action = cc.repeat(sprite_action, rand);
sprite.runAction(repeat_action);
```